# Libquicktime support on Linux

Tags: linux, video, quicktime

I am trying to encode and decode (playback and record) a .mov file on Linux with libquicktime. This is the source for libquicktime: http://libquicktime.sourceforge.net/

and these are the APIs: http://libquicktime.sourceforge.net/doc/apiref/lqt_8h.html

I am trying to use these to playback the video file on Linux. However have not yet found any reference code as to how to use the APIs.

Does someone have any knowledge in this area that you can share?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is play a Quicktime video file, your purposes may be better served by ffmpeg/libav. It has support for the Quicktime container format, as well as many others.

Comment: Thanks, however for some reasons, I am constrained to use libquicktime only, so looking for resources on that part.